Combine basename with default value on parameter
I want to write a zsh script (zsh 5.8.1),  which accepts a single, optional parameter which is a file path. I want to derive a variable with the following properties:

If the parameter is non-empty, the variable should hold the basename of the file
Otherwise, the variable should be empty

Additional restriction: The shell script should run with set -u.
I don't see how I can do both conditions in one go.
The first condition can easily be fulfilled by:
var=$1:t

but this produces an error (due to set -u), if there is no parameter.
The second condition can be fulfilled by:
var=${1:-}

and I could combine them in two statements:
var=${1:-}
var=$var:t

Can this be done with a single assignment? I tried:
var=${ ${1:-}:t }

but this produces the error zsh: bad substitution.

What about simply testing the number of given arg and keep the passed one if there is one, or set the default if none is passed?

@Jib : This would hardly be called "with a single assignment". I would need one test, and then an assignment in the if and the else branch. I would like to do with a single parameter substitution.

var=${${1:-}:t} (no spaces) appears to work, but I don't have 5.8.1 to test against.

@Gairfowl : It does. If you post this as answer, I will accept it.

To work with set -u consider the ${name+word} form of parameter expansion

@rowboat: I don't see how this parameter expansion could help here. Maybe you could add as alternate answer, how this would be used here.

Nested expansions are supported in zsh, but usually as a single token (i.e., no spaces):
#!/usr/bin/env zsh -u
# -u: NO_UNSET - error if referencing a variable that has not been set
var=${${1:-}:t}
typeset -p var

Testing:
> ./tst 'dir/lvl2/file.txt'
typeset var=file.txt
> ./tst abcdefg
typeset var=abcdefg
> ./tst
typeset var=''




If the parameter is non-empty, the variable should hold the basename of the file
Otherwise, the variable should be empty


var=${1:+$1:t}

var is set to $1:t if 1 is set and not empty. The alternative value expansion format (${parameter+word}) will not raise an error for an unset parameter when using the nounset option.
